# [SQLite Query]: build tab with 0 values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to realize a query but I don't know how to built it.
My tabs is something like this:

**date, type_fruit, price**

and records are something like this:

```
date_1, orange, 10$
date_1, orange, 5$
date_2, peach, 3$
date_3, banana, 25$
date_3, apple, 10$
```

My goal is build a tab like this:

```
| ---------------------------------------
|            | orange | banana |  apple |
| date_1     |   15$  |   0$   |    0$  |
| date_3     |    0$  |  25$   |   10$  |
|----------------------------------------
```

but...but...taking just top 3 bought fruits!
So, taking from SQLite DB just orange (10$+5$), banana (25$) and apple(10$) and not taking peach (only 3$).
Could anyone help me please?

PS: I hope I explained my problem in a clear way, sorry for some english mistake.

Comment: I will use this query with Android.

Answer (score 0):

This is example for SQL SERVER.
IF you use another DB maybe will be chages.

```
if  OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#example') IS NOT NULL

drop table  #example

go

create table #example

(

    [date] date,

    type_fruit varchar(100),

    price int

)

insert into #example

select

 getdate() as [date], 'orange' as type_fruit, 10 as price

union select

getdate(), 'orange', 5

union select

getdate()-1, 'peach', 3

union select

getdate()-2, 'banana', 25

union select

getdate()-2, 'apple', 10


SELECT [DATE], ISNULL(orange,0)orange, ISNULL(banana,0)orange,ISNULL(apple,0)orange

FROM (

SELECT [date],  type_fruit, price

FROM #example) up

PIVOT (SUM(PRICE) FOR type_fruit IN ( orange, banana,apple)) AS pvt

WHERE isnull(orange,-1)+isnull(banana,-1)+ISNULL(apple,-1) <> -3

GO
```

I hope this is will hekp you.

Comment: I think this is not what I need, or could you explain me how to use this informations?

Comment: please run this script. if you want understand this you need read about pivot.[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: This is not what I asked...I need just a query/queries to use with JAVA in Android. Thank you anyway